# Decorated trees using forest package

Tags: graphs, forest, trees

Using the package "forest", firstly i would like to draw the following tree (where terminal vertices could be either a dot or a letter), i could write a tree where all vertices are dots or all vertices are letters but i could'nt mix the two type in order to obtain this tree:

[image]

Secondly, i would like to modify the position of the decorations. I was able to draw a tree with decoration under the vertices:
[image]

and a tree with decorations above the vertices:

[image]

But I would like that the decorations of terminal vertices appear above them and the one of the root under it. How can i do that?

Comment: Please add a minimal (non-)working example which shows what you already tried.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. The reason you haven't gotten responses before now is that most users will ignore posts that do not contain a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Your MWE should start with `\documentclass`, include all relevant `\usepackage` commands, end with `\end{document}` and compile without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. Always include a MWE when you post a question.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions:

You can define a node style (I used `dot` in the code below). If you want to label the dot node, add `label={<direction>:<contents>}` to the appropriate node. You can use angles, compass directions or position directions for `<direction>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{dot/.style={fill, circle, minimum width=1.5mm, inner sep=0, outer sep=0}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=north, s sep=8mm}
[, dot, label={below:$\mathbf{e}_i$}
    [$\mathbf{n}_1$]
    [, dot]
    [$\mathbf{n}_2$]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can use the parent and child anchors together with the `\path` command to draw these.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=north, parent anchor=north, child anchor=south}
[$\mathbf{e}_i$
  [$\mathbf{n}_1$]
  []
  [$\mathbf{n}_2$]
]
\path[fill](.parent anchor) circle[radius=2pt];
\path[fill](!2.child anchor) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```